# Time managment with queue and threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I have an object that can be used by a thread for some time and then i have to stop using it for a predefined period (like a banish for X seconds). then the thread can use it again.

I want suggestions of how should I implement this,
I was thinking of FIFO queue that is holding key,value pair for each object.
the object as the key and the period which it can start working again as the value.
When the object has to stop working it will be added to the queue with the time it has been added.
Then I have to check every X seconds if the first element in the queue can be used, this is why I think this is not a good solution for this problem.

What is the best way to implement this?
I'm using python, so examples in python will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [sched](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) module.  It lets you submit jobs to run in the future.

Example from docs:

```
>>> import sched, time
>>> s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
>>> def print_time(): print "From print_time", time.time()
...
>>> def print_some_times():
...     print time.time()
...     s.enter(5, 1, print_time, ())
...     s.enter(10, 1, print_time, ())
...     s.run()
...     print time.time()
...
>>> print_some_times()
930343690.257
From print_time 930343695.274
From print_time 930343700.273
930343700.276
```